# Probability distribution of a ten slot three state system

Tags: probability-distributions

I have ten slots, and each slot can take the value 1, 2 or 3.  The product of the ten slots is then calculated.  What is the probability distribution of all possible products for this system?

Some are easy, for example a product of 1 can only be produced by 1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1=1.  But what about, say, 108?

To start with, I'm assuming that 1, 2 and 3 occur equally likely, but eventally I would like to be able to change their likelihoods and still be able to work out the probability distribution of the products.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a trinomial distribution with the added complexity of determining the number of $1s, 2s$ and $3s$ for every "possible" outcome.

Example: $P(108)$

$108 = 2^2\cdot 3^3\cdot 1^5$

Using the trinomial equation:

$$P(108) = \frac{10!}{2!\cdot3!\cdot 5!}\cdot (\frac{1}{3})^{10} = .042676$$

Comment: Hi Phil. Great, thanks for the response, you've given me something to research. From your example it looks like I need to vary the product, try to guess ways it can be achieved, then use the formula to work out how likely those ways are. Is there a more algorithmic way I can do it, which doesn't involve as much brain power?

Comment: Richard, these kind of things, like finding the factors, are best done with a computer program which can do the laborious trial and error series of divisions very quickly.to find the prime factors. The program would then add in the number of ones to bring the count up to the number of slots and then perform the calculation above. I don't know of a more simpler manual way to do this.